# Write a script that installs a package file automatically with limited interaction from user

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a package installer from terminal and have it complete with limited interaction from the user. This will need to be ran on any computer.

The bash script I have so far is:

```
sudo installer -store -pkg "/Users/username/Desktop/test.pkg" -target /
```

It will not complete and I am getting the following error:
installer: Can't load package "/Users/username/Desktop/test.pkg": The requested URL was not found on this server.

Not sure what this error means as I'm a newbie to scripting. Please advise what is needed to fix this.

Comment: The man page recommends against using `-store` together with `sudo`, you probably don't need that option anyway as it is primarily intend to test package installation before submitting them to the store. Also the error message indicates that `installer` can't access the package file, is it in a place where `root` can access it? Also, does the package itself work, i.e. can you install it by double-clicking it in Finder?

Comment: @patrix Did you delete my comment?

Comment: @jsejcksn Your comment got deleted automatically by the system when I put this on hold for being a duplicate of the question your comment linked to. It is now shown on top of the question.

Comment: @patrix Thanks for explaining. If that was in the SE site use documentation, I missed that part.

Comment: @jsejcksn You'll probably find it documented somewhere on meta.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to run any command using `sudo` without user interaction because the user will have to supply an administrative password.

Comment: OK, that is fine. Any Idea how this script would complete with limited interaction?

Comment: @MacMania How is the script being run? Also, is the .pkg file necessary?

Comment: Script is being run via bash script and yes, the package is necessary.

Comment: See the link I commented on your question. You might be getting the error because that username doesn't exist. Try using the `~` to get to the user folder instead of the absolute path.